# Getting the middle character in a odd length string

Tags: python, string, function, find

```
def get_middle_character(odd_string):
    variable = len(odd_string)
    x = str((variable/2))
    middle_character = odd_string.find(x)
    middle_character2 = odd_string[middle_character]
    return middle_character2



def main():
    print('Enter a odd length string: ')
    odd_string = input()
    print('The middle character is', get_middle_character(odd_string))

main()
```

I need to figure out how to print the middle character in a given odd length string. But when I run this code, I only get the last character. What is the problem?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. Do you know what `x` is? What `str.find` does? I'd suggest you step through it with e.g. [Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html). Note that once you have the index of the middle character, you're pretty much done!

Comment: You need to read the documentation on string methods because you are using them incorrectly. `odd_string.find(x)` will return `-1` because you are searching for the string representation of the number `variable/2`. Thus, `.find` will return -1, and `odd_string[middle_character]` will return the last character of the string (as per Python's negative indexing).

Answer (score 2):

You need to think more carefully about what your code is actually doing. Let's do this with an example:

```
def get_middle_character(odd_string):
```

Let's say that we call `get_middle_character('hello')`, so `odd_string` is `'hello'`:

```
    variable = len(odd_string)  # variable = 5
```

Everything is OK so far.

```
    x = str((variable/2))  # x = '2'
```

This is the first thing that is obviously odd - why do you want the string `'2'`? That's the index of the middle character, don't you just want an integer? Also you only need one pair of parentheses there, the other set is redundant.

```
    middle_character = odd_string.find(x)  # middle_character = -1
```

Obviously you can't `str.find` the substring `'2'` in `odd_string`, because it was never there. `str.find` returns `-1` if it cannot find the substring; you should use `str.index` instead, which gives you a nice clear `ValueError` when it can't find the substring.

Note that even if you were searching for the middle character, rather than the stringified index of the middle character, you would get into trouble as `str.find` gives the *first* index at which the substring appears, which may not be the one you're after (consider `'lolly'.find('l')`...).

```
    middle_character2 = odd_string[middle_character]  # middle_character2 = 'o'
```

As Python allows negative indexing from the end of a sequence, `-1` is the index of the last character.

```
    return middle_character2  # return 'o'
```

You could actually have simplified to `return odd_string[middle_character]`, and removed the superfluous assignment; you'd have still had the wrong answer, but from neater code (and without `middle_character2`, which is a terrible name).

---

Hopefully you can now see where you went wrong, and it's trivially obvious what you should do to fix it. Next time use e.g. [Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html) to debug your code before asking a question here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply access character based on index of string and *string slicing*. For example:

```
>>> s = '1234567'
>>> middle_index = len(s)/2
>>> first_half, middle, second_half = s[:middle_index], s[middle_index], s[middle_index+1:]
>>> first_half, middle, second_half
('123', '4', '567')
```

Explanation:

- `str[:n]`: returns string from 0th index to `n-1`th index
- `str[n]`: returns value at nth index
- `str[n:]`: returns value from nth index till end of list

Answer (score 0):

Should be like below:

```
def get_middle_character(odd_string):
    variable = len(odd_string)/2
    middle_character = odd_string[variable +1]
    return middle_character
```

Answer (score 0):

i know its too late but i post my solution
I hope it will be useful ;)

```
def get_middle_char(string):
    if len(string) % 2 == 0:
        return None
    elif len(string) <= 1:
        return None

    str_len = int(len(string)/2))

    return string[strlen]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
reversedString = ''

print('What is your name')

str = input()
idx = len(str)
print(idx)

str_to_iterate = str
for char in str_to_iterate[::-1]:
    print(char)

evenodd = len(str) % 2
if evenodd == 0:
    print('even')
else:
    print('odd')

l = str

if len(l) % 2 == 0:
    x = len(l) // 2
    y = len(l) // 2 - 1
    print(l[x], l[y])
else:
    n = len(l) // 2
    print(l[n])
```

Comment: Simple code based around the idx of any given input and returns the values of the middle even and odd scenarios presented.