# I have a variable as a tuple how can I return it as a string

Tags: python

I want to get the middle letter of a word, but I want the result to print as a string. How can I do so?

```
def get_middle(word):
    a = int(len(word))
    b = int(len(word)/2) 
    c = int(len(word)/2 - 1)
    d = int(len(word)/2 - 0,5)
    if a%2==0:
      print(str(word[b] + word[c]))


    elif a%2==1:
        print(str(word[d]))

    else:
        print("That's not a sring!")
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40455724/getting-the-middle-character-in-a-odd-length-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return middle part of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47463781/return-middle-part-of-string)

Comment: How will `a%2` ever be different to 0 and 1 at the same time so that the else statement is executed?

Comment: "If the length is neither even nor odd, it's not a string"?

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_middle(word):
    if len(word)%2 == 1:
        return word[:int((len(word)-1)/2)]+word[int((len(word)-1)/2)+1:]
```